# openCV will not open mp4 files

Tags: python, opencv, video

```
import cv2     # for capturing videos
import math   # for mathematical operations
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    # for plotting the images
import numpy as np    # for mathematical operations


count = 0
videoFile = "video.mp4"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile)   # capturing the video from the given path
frameRate = cap.get(30) #frame rate
x=1
while(cap.isOpened()):
    frameId = cap.get(1) #current frame number
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if (ret != True):
        break
    if (frameId % math.floor(frameRate) == 0):
        filename ="frame%d.jpg" % count;count+=1
        cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)
cap.release()
```

above is the following code I am using to break up a mp4 video that I have, however, I noticed that openCV can not read any videos ( I have already tried with a .avi video).

Running:
    OS: Windows 10
    Using Spyder (Python 3.7.3) and OpenCV 4.2. 
Has anyone else ran into this problem? Is there a work around?

Comment: Is the mp4 file in your working directory? If not, then you need to provide a proper full path to the file. Or perhaps you need to install FFMPEG. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html

Comment: Yes, I have the mp4 file saved in the same directory  working with the python script.

Comment: Or perhaps you need to install FFMPEG. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html

Comment: I believe I have already installed that. However, if I did not properly set that up how can I tell? Is there a specific file I need?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know much about reading video files in OpenCV. Never done that yet. I was just suggesting to check some of the simple things. As for testing FFMPEG, just use it in command line mode outside of OpenCV. Also try reading just the first frame in a simple script. Also search Google for instructions on installing FFMPEG with OpenCV.